# Can't Test React Native Components in a Monorepo

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

Hi I'm trying to test React-Native components in a monorepo.

I have an `apps/mobile` folder with a react-native app in it.
I have a `packages/ui` with a simple button component that only uses react-native.

I have a unit test in `apps/mobile` that imports the button from `ui`.

If I run the test I get an error `__fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set, cannot invoke native modules`
If I do `jest.mock('ui')` the test passes.

However I don't believe I have any native code in my packages/ui component. What am I doing wrong?
My Jest config looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  preset: 'jest-expo',
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['./src/.*/__mocks__/*'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./test-utils/jest-setup-after-env.ts'],
  testMatch: ['**/?(*.)test.!(*.){js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  // https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)',
  ],
  /**
   * Jest's require algorithm adds .json to the list of extensions it can import, and it prioritizes .json over .tsx
   * We want to do it to avoid to import app.json instead App.tsx, for example, what was happening on the file App.test.tsx when ran jest tests.
   */
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
}
```

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to this? I am having the same problem after upgrading to React Native 0.69

Comment: I am also having this issue. @AndrewKirchmyer Are you sure it happened after upgrading to 0.69?

Comment: @MatinZadehDolatabad I found that my issue wasn't caused by 0.69. When I upgraded react-native I also moved all my test dependencies from the root package.json to the workspace package.json and that is what seemed to cause all the errors for me. Moving them back to the root packaged fixed the issues. I wish I had an answer as to why.

Comment: did you find a way to fix the `__fbBatchedBridgeConfig` issue?

Answer (score 0):

When running tests within the app/mobile package, React Native mocks are automatically created for the local paths within that package. However, when code from the packages/ui or any other external package uses React Native, the mocks are not initialized by default.

**Solution**
Add following in your jest configuration

```
moduleNameMapper: {
// Specific mapping for react-native from app/mobile folder
'^react-native$': '<rootDir>/app/mobile/node_modules/react-native',
}
```